# pdf to csv to use tabula

Tags: csv, pdf, tabula

When the pdf file is transferred to the csv file using tabula, several pages of the pdf file overlap vertically and are displayed.
For example, if apple is in (1,a) , banana is in (2,b), and grape is in (3,c)
Most of them go in exactly, but sometimes apples and bananas in (1,a) and grapes in (2,b)
I don't know exactly why.

```
df = tabula.read_pdf("sample.pdf", pages='all')[0]      
        tabula.convert_into("sample.pdf", "output.csv", output_format="csv", stream=False, pages='all')
        r_csv = pd.read_csv("output.csv", on_bad_lines='skip') 
        save_xlsx = pd.ExcelWriter("pray.xlsx")     
        r_csv.to_excel(save_xlsx, index = False)
```

Above is part of my code. I hope for help.

I want rows and columns to be right